# ng-enter directive and select attribute confilicted with each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Consider this code:

```
<typeahead class="typeahead" 
           search="searchPersonage(term)" 
           select="selectPersonage(item)" 
           ng-model="typeaheadModel"
           ng-enter='selectCustomer(typeaheadModel)'>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr typeahead-item="customerPhone" 
                ng-repeat="customerPhone in customerPhones">
                <td>{{customerPhone.Title}}</td>
                <td>{{customerPhone.Value}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</typeahead>
```

as you can see I have a `typeahead` tag and in this tag i have `ng-enter` directive and `select` attribute. What I need is when an unkown phone number is entered by user and if that number is not in typeahead objects and then user hits the enter button, I want it to be pushed in an array. But I want only that unknown number to be pushed.

However, now when user hits the enter button, not only the number is pushed in the array but also the `select` method is called. This causes the unknown number to be pushed into the target array, alongside an object from typeahead data source.

```
$scope.selectCustomer = function (item) {
    $scope.selectedPhones.push({
        Value: item.Value,
        Title: item.Title
    });
};
$scope.selectPhone = function (item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.customerPhones.length; i++) {
        if (item == $scope.customerPhones[i].Title
            || item == $scope.customerPhones[i].Value) {
            $scope.selectedPhones.push({
                Value: $scope.customerPhones[i].Value,
                Title: $scope.customerPhones[i].Title
            });
            $scope.customerPhones = [];
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        if (item.match("^09[0-3][0-9]{8}$")) {
            $scope.selectedPhones.push({
                Value: item,
                Title: 'Unknown'
            });
            $scope.customerPhones = [];
        }
        else {
            toaster.showError('This number is not valid  : ' + item);
            $scope.customerPhones = [];
        }
    }

    $scope.typeaheadModel = "";
    flag = true;
}
```

Comment: what is <typeahead> ? which angular directive? Can you share that directive source?